# How do I combine text inputs in JSON?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to combine some text and then a score from a scoreboard but I cannot get this to work.

This is what I have currently:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"test","score":{"name":"player","objective":"scoreboard"}}
```

When I run the command it only displays the text but not the score. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

`/tellraw` can directly use an array:

```
/tellraw @s [{"text":"abc"},{"text":"123"}]
```

[ExpertCoder14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/250180/expertcoder14) showed that it's also possible to do that in strings in NBT, which I believed to be impossible before.

Alternatively you can also use "`extra`", in which you can then use arbitrarily many components again:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ oak_sign{Text1:"{\"text\":\"abc\",\"extra\":[{\"text\":\"123\"},{\"text\":\"lalala\"}]}"}
```

Comment: Are you quite sure? I've been using arrays in NBT JSON text tags for quite a while now, and it's never failed me. Are there drawbacks to using arrays in JSON NBT tags over `extra`?

Comment: I didn't know that! I don't know if Slicedlime even knows it. I should tell him in his next mapmaking stream.

Answer (score 1):

Fabian Röling is correct that you can use an array in areas where your raw JSON text is inputted as a command input:

```
/tellraw @s [{"text":"abc"},{"text":"123"}]
```

However, when you are inputting raw JSON text into a `string` tag in NBT data, you can still use an array. Make sure to put the `,` separator after the `}` but *before* the `]`.

```
/data merge block ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"[{\"text\":\"Custom Name of Chest\"}, {\"text\":\"Some More Text\"}]"}
```

Note that although it looks different, it is technically the same as the second example from Fabian Röling below, based on the way it behaves when adding other components to change font style and colour. This is evident because each section takes the formatting of the first unless provided with override instructions.

If you  are playing on Minecraft 1.14+, why not try enclosing the whole data tag string using `'`s instead of `"`s? That way, you don't need to escape each double quote with a `\`.
Like this:

```
/data merge block ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'[{"text":"Custom Name of Chest"}, {"text":"Some More Text"}]'}
```

Comment: Wow, this actually works, I didn't know that! I'll edit my answer to make clear that it's another option, please edits yours if you want.